# Effect of changing electric field on the magnetic field due to a single moving charge

Tags: electromagnetism

A point charge q is moving in a straight line with a velocity $\textbf{v}$. The magnetic field due to it at a point P, whose position with respect to the charge is given by $\textbf{r}$, is usually derived in textbooks using Biot-Savart's law as

$$\textbf{B} = \frac{\mu_oq}{4\pi}\frac{\textbf{v}\times\textbf{r}}{\lVert \textbf{r}\rVert^3}$$

I have a doubt whether this is quite right. Consider an electron moving at a constant speed along a line AB from left to right. Consider another point C on the same line to the right of B. As the electron moves, the electric field at C due to the electron changes with time. This means that a magnetic field exists at the point which is not taken into consideration in the above equation.

Biot-Savart's law is true for steady currents in conducting wires. Such currents do not create an electric field outside the wire. But the same is not true of free charges.

So is the above equation incorrect?

Comment: See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biot–Savart_law#Point_charge_at_constant_velocity).

Comment: *This means that a magnetic field exists at the point.* That conclusion is incorrect. All you can conclude is that the curl of the magnetic field is nonzero there.

Comment: If the curl of the magnetic field is nonzero, there must be a magnetic field that has the curl.

Comment: @JerroldFranklin There is a nonzero magnetic field off the axis. The field on the axis is zero. The curl on the axis is nonzero.

Comment: You are right.  I answered too quickly, but there is no need to put the point C on the axis.

Answer (score 2):

The electromagnetic field of a point charge moving with constant velocity $\mathbf{v}$ is most easily found by performing a Lorentz transformation on the field strength tensor of the pure Coulomb field generated by the charge in its rest frame. The final result can be found in any reasonable text-book on electrodynamics, $$\begin{align} \mathbf{E} &= \frac{q \,\mathbf{r}}{4\pi \epsilon_0 |\mathbf{r}|^3} \frac{1-\mathbf{v}^2/c^2}{(1-\mathbf{v}^2 \sin^2 \theta/c^2)^{3/2}}, \quad \mathbf{B}= \mathbf{v} \times \mathbf{E}/c^2,   \end{align} \tag{1} \label{1}$$ where $\mathbf{r} = \mathbf{x}-\mathbf{v}\,  t$ is the vector from the momentary position $\mathbf{v} t$ of the charge to the point $\mathbf{x}$ where the field is measured and $\theta$ denotes the angle between $\mathbf{v}$ and $\mathbf{r}$. Your formula is obtained in the limit $|\mathbf{v}| \lt \!\! \lt c$ inserting $|\mathbf{v}|/c \to 0$  in $\mathbf{E}$ and using $1/c^2= \epsilon_0 \mu_0$.

The electromagnetic field given in \eqref{1} satisfies of course Maxwell's equation for the charge density $\rho(t, \mathbf{x})= q\, \delta^{(3)}(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{v} t)$ and the current density $\mathbf{j}(t, \mathbf{x})= \rho(t, \mathbf{x}) \, \mathbf{v}$ of the point charge.

Comment: So at a point like C in my question, $\sin\theta $ is zero  and $\textbf{E} $ points in the direction of $ \textbf{r}$, and $\textbf{B}$ is therefore zero, which is also the result from the usual derivation.

But E varies with time at C, according to your equation. So does a magnetic field exist at C?

Comment: @phil342 For your point C you have $\mathbf{r}= r \mathbf{v}/|\mathbf{v}|$ and $\mathbf{E}= (q/4\pi \epsilon_0 r^2) \mathbf{v}/|\mathbf{v}|$ and consequently $\mathbf{B}$ vanishes at this point. Of course, $\mathbf{E}(t, \mathbf{x})$ changes with time, but this does not imply that $\mathbf{B}(t, \mathbf{x})$ is not allowed to vanish along the line where charge is moving (but it is non-vanishing around this line). Simply insert the electromagnetic field given in my answer into Maxwell's equations and convince yourself that everything works out perfectly fine. Also a drawing might be helpful!

Answer (score 2):

Hyperon's answer correctly gives the E and B fields of the moving charge. Your fields are the nonrelativistic limit of these fields. You are right, there will be a time-dependent electric field at a point C further ahead of the position of the particle. Its curl will equal the magnetic field given by the formula, so there is no extra field.

Comment: Can you show me how the mathematics works out? That is, how the curl of the time-varying electric field gives the magnetic field given by the formula..

Comment: You can take the  Curl of E and the time derivative of B, as each are given in equation 1 above.  This is quite complicated, but is unnecessary. As Hyperon stated, Maxwell's equations still apply, so $\nabla\times{\vec E}=-\partial_t{\vec B}$.